# Disable \tabulinesep for some rows with tabu package

Tags: tables, spacing, tabu

The `\tabulinesep` parameter with `tabu` package provide good paddings for tables with variant heights. But when using it with `diagbox` package, the paddings cause problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,diagbox,tabu}
\begin{document}
tabulinesep
{\setlength{\tabulinesep}{3pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
$\dfrac12$ & $\dfrac34$ & $\dfrac56$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}}
%
extrarowsep
{\setlength{\extrarowsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
$\dfrac12$ & $\dfrac34$ & $\dfrac56$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}}
\end{document}
```

How could I disable `\tabulinesep` padding for only the first row of the table?

As you could see in the above example, `\extrarowsep` doesn't give the desired paddings. Therefore I would like to stick to `\tabulinesep` solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, I propose `\addstackgap` of the `stackengine` package, which only needs to be applied to the tallest cell in an oversized row.  Here I use it in conjunction with `\extrarowsep`, but depending on what look the OP seeks, that is not necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,diagbox,tabu,stackengine}
\begin{document}
tabulinesep
{\setlength{\tabulinesep}{3pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
$\dfrac12$ & $\dfrac34$ & $\dfrac56$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}}
%
\Centerstack{addstackgap + extrarowsep}
{\setlength{\extrarowsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
\addstackgap[4pt]{$\dfrac12$} & $\dfrac34$ & $\dfrac56$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to enlarge `\extrarowsep`, for example to 8pt:

```
\setlength{\extrarowsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
$\dfrac{1}{2}$ & $\dfrac{3}{4}$ & $\dfrac{5}{6}$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

In this case are all rows higher, but look similar as you show in right picture ...
**Edit:**
Another way for enlarge on row's height (for your particular problem) is to put rule in one row cell:

```
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{X}{Y} & Z & Z\\
\hline
$\dfrac12$\rule[-2.4ex]{0pt}{6ex} & $\dfrac34$ & $\dfrac56$ \\
\hline
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

Of course, this is not general solution.

Comment: Then there will be much more vertical space for the third row, which is not what I want...